# Um arquivo de um hotel e restaurante

Tags: uso-de-palavras

É correto escrever "hotel e restaurante" numa frase como esta:

> Ele traduziu um arquivo de um hotel e restaurante.

O hotel e o restaurante pertencem ao mesmo dono e tem o mesmo nome.

Comment: Creio que a dúvida seja quanto à necessidade de repetir a preposição e/ou de evidenciar o artigo nos itens não-iniciais de uma enumeração. Por exemplo: "*arquivo de um hotel e restaurante*" vs. "*arquivo de um hotel e de um restaurante*". Seria isso?

Comment: Pode ser! Eu estou confusa. ahaha Então, eu só quero saber se a primeira forma é correta. O que acontece é que "Hotel e Restaurante (nome)" é o nome do negócio, entendeu? Parece que tem bastantes negócios assim.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=hotel+e+restaurante&oq=hotel+e+restaurante&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30k1l4.938.5370.0.5539.19.19.0.0.0.0.154.2049.0j17.17.0.foo%2Cersl%3D1%2Cfett%3D1%2Cewh%3D0%2Cnso-enksa%3D0%2Cnso-enfk%3D1%2Cnso-usnt%3D1%2Cnso-qnt-npqp%3D0-1%2Cnso-qnt-npdq%3D0-45%2Cnso-qnt-npt%3D0-09%2Cnso-qnt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mnp%3D0-045%2Ccspa-dspm-nm-mxp%3D0-1125%2Cnso-unt-npqp%3D0-15%2Cnso-unt-npdq%3D0-25%2Cnso-unt-npt%3D0-06%2Cnso-unt-ndc%3D300%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mnp%3D0-0075%2Ccspa-uipm-nm-mxp%3D0-0525.3..0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.17.2046...0j0i131k1j0i13i30k1.-u2AS4H4u1g

Comment: É correta minha frase então? Dá a impressão que eu quero levar ou não?
Obrigada. :)

Answer (score 1):

Existem estabelecimentos comerciais que funcionam simultaneamente como hotel e como restaurante.

Quando desejamos nos referir textualmente a um estabelecimento desses por intermédio do **nome comercial** desse estabelecimento, utilizamos o **substantivo próprio** que identifica e individualiza esse estabelecimento. Exemplo:

- *Gostei muito da comida que me foi servida no quarto do **Hotel e Restaurante Brisamar**.*

Porém, quando desejamos nos referir textualmente a um estabelecimento desses por intermédio da **categoria de estabelecimento comercial** a que o estabelecimento pertence, utilizamos o **substantivo comum** que identifica e individualiza essa categoria (esse tipo) de estabelecimento. Exemplo:

- *Gostei muito da comida que me foi servida no quarto do **hotel-restaurante**.*

Como esse tipo (essa categoria) de estabelecimento comercial refere-se, concomitantemente, a hotel e a restaurante, o respectivo substantivo comum é um **nome composto**: cada uma das duas palavras ("hotel" e "restaurante") que designam tal tipo/categoria de estabelecimento comercial pertence a uma mesma unidade sintagmática e semântica. É por isto que tal substantivo comum deve ser grafado com **hífen**, assim: hotel-restaurante.

Consequentemente, está errado escrever "Ele traduziu um arquivo de um hotel e restaurante". A maneira correta (norma culta) de se escrever essa frase é esta:

> *Ele traduziu um arquivo de um **hotel-restaurante**.*